Decomposition of a Ring with Unity into Indecomposable Projective Modules: General Case vs. Artinian Case
Let $R$ be a ring with unity. When $R$ is an Artinian ring, we can always obtain a decomposition:
$$
R \simeq P_1 \oplus P_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n,
$$
where $P_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are all indecomposable projective modules.
Now, the question arises: when $R$ is an arbitrary ring with unity, can we also obtain a decomposition
$$
R \simeq P_1 \oplus P_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus P_n,
$$
where $P_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ are all indecomposable projective modules? Or is there a counterexample?

The same result is true for Noetherian rings $R$.

Every domain is an example too. I've expanded my answer a bit...

Consider $R=\prod_\mathbb N F$ where $F$ is any field.
If it were the product of finitely many indecomposable submodules, then at least one of them is infinitely generated.  Call that one $I$.
But for any nonzero $x\in I$, the submodule $xR$ is a nontrivial summand of $R$ (this is a property of von Neumann regular rings), and hence it's also a summand of $I$.  That means $I$ was not indecomposable after all.

Obviously, one sufficient condition would be for the ring to be orthogonally finite (meaning no infinite collections of pairwise orthogonal nonzero idempotents exist.  The counterexample given above is clearly not orthogonally finite.)
That means, anticlimactically, that any domain is an example, and most interesting domains are not fields/division rings.
Of course, a right or left Noetherian ring has this property, because it guarantees inductively subdividing summands cannot continue forever.
Another famous class of rings of this type are semiperfect rings, which can be characterized by the existence of a finite set $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of nonzero orthogonal idempotents such that $\sum e_i=1$ and $e_iRe_i$ is a local ring for every $i$.  These conditions ensure that $e_iR$ is irreducible and that $\bigoplus e_iR=R$.
But there are still many orthogonally finite rings not of those types: the ring of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb Z&\mathbb Q \\ 0&\mathbb Q\end{bmatrix}$, and the trivial extension $T(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z_{2^\infty})$ are some.
